# Is diying a strong jet engine possible wih basic tools

Tags: jet-engine, engine, turbojet

Is it possible to manufacture a jet engine that provides 500 newtons of thrust with relatively primitive tools like a lathe or so , if someone did something similar can you provide me with the knowledge you obtained please.

Comment: This is off topic here. Engineering subject, rather. But no, it's not possible.

Comment: You could do it with a CNC mill to make a centrifugal compressor and turbine, housing etc. Or with really basic tools, just get a turbocharger and build the burner cans to join the compressor side and turbine side together. Lot's of ppl have built little engines out of automotive turbos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would require far, far more than just a lathe.  You'll have to do 3D milling of some fairly exotic materials to create turbines, sophisticated spin balancing tools, etc.

There's a DIY guy on youtube that will provide some insights on what's involved:

[Warped Perception](https://www.youtube.com/@WarpedPerception)

Also, I *highly* recommend AgentJayZ if you have an interest in a deeper dive into all things jet engine.  He does not work on DIY engines, he overhauls/refurbs industrial and aircraft jet engines, but his videos can provide deep insights into how turbojets actually work.

[AgentJayZ](https://www.youtube.com/@AgentJayZ)

Comment: The manufacturing state of the art and the best engineers available in the early 1940's were only barely able to make functional jet engines. Even with the knowledge on the internet available now, I doubt that the tools in most DIY shops can improve on what the best in the world were doing then.

Answer (score 0):

To take the heat and huge rotational stresses, most of the engine has to be manufactured from *superalloys* which have been subject to exotic process treatments to maximize their strength. Those process steps are completely beyond the capabilities of any garage shop.

They are also enormously difficult to machine to the super high tolerances required in modern, high-powered jet engines that must last tens of thousands of hours at full power without failure.